# Multiple OR frange in DSE Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have to dates, originalArrivalEta and realArrivalEta, and I would like to do a Solr search based on the difference between these dates.

The main problem is that my time range is not continuous, it is spliced. So, for example, I want a range between 3 and 5 days for both later and sooner dates.

I know can do:

```
fq: {!frange l=-172800000 u=172800000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta)
```

But, since fq is always concatenating I cannot do:

```
fq: {!frange l=-172800000 u=-86400000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta)
fq: {!frange l=86400000 u=172800000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta)
```

I have also tried to do a pure negative by basically trying to remove the "hole" in the middle of the range that I am not interested in:

```
fq: {!frange l=-172800000 u=172800000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta)
fq: -{!frange l=-86400000 u=86400000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta)
```

I tried with NOT and OR, but neither seem to work.

I have also tried to use a fl by defining it:

```
fl: timediff:ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta)
```

But I don't seem to be able to filter by it. And I am not sure my current technology stack allow me to do this anyway, since I am currently using Cassandra DSE 5.1 engine, that uses Solr 6.0.

Is there a way to use multiple frange that are not concatenated? 
Is there some kind of way I can put this in the q like:

```
q: ( {!frange l=-172800000 u=-86400000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta) OR {!frange l=86400000 u=172800000 incu=true incl=true}ms(originalArrivalEta, realArrivalEta) )
```

I know performance will be likely impacted, but if there is no other way to do it, then better slow than never.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You [can use `_query_` to run other queries inline](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Usingthe_magicfields__val_and_query_) - maybe that would work? You also have [the `abs` function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions), which would allow you to only define one range. For better performance I'd suggest indexing this field as well, and populating it with an update chain - that way you can use any query syntax without having to invoke functions.

Comment: abs! of course, such a simple an elegant answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_query_` to run other queries inline - that could work.

In this case you do however [have the `abs` function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions), which would allow you to only define one range.

For better performance I'd suggest indexing this field as well, and populating it with an update chain - that way you can use any query syntax without having to invoke functions.